# hibernate persist method “called outside of transaction” meaning

Tags: hibernate, transactions

> persist() makes a transient instance persistent. However, it does not
>   guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent
>   instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time.
>   persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement
>   if it is called outside of transaction boundaries. This is useful in
>   long-running conversations with an extended Session/persistence
>   context.

This line "persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries." seems to be confusing. If we called the persist(), then it is already part of the session. Then why does the question of "outside of transaction" arrive?

Answer (score 1):

In special case, you can call `persist()` outside of transaction, for example if you are using extended type persistence context. Consider this scenario in purchasing apps:

You have defined `EntityManager` with extended type

```
@PersistenceContext(type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;
```

you have a method that will create `Order` when user create new order.

```
// this method is called outside transaction
public void createOrder() {
   this.order = new Order();
   em.persist(order); //the entity is not flushed to the database, but rather remain managed by the entity manager
}
```

than you have method that will add `Item` to `Order` entity when user start adding items to be included in the order.

```
// this method is also called outside transaction and can be called as many as items added by user
public void addOrderItems(Item item) {
   em.persist(item);// also not flushed to the database, but rather remain managed by the entity manager
   this.order.getItems().add(item);
   item.setOrder(this.order);
}
```

whenever user is done with the order then completing the order process will execute this method

```
// this is where the transaction started
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED) 
public void completeOrder() {
   em.flush();
}
```

because now we have a transaction, then the entities will be inserted to the database.

In other words all `persist()` operations are queued, and when there is a transaction the queue is executed.